# Reference request: bounded derived categories and their Auslander-Reiten quivers

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, quiver, cluster-algebra

I have some knowledge of Auslander-Reiten theory, tilting theory, derived categories and triangulated categories though I still find most proofs using derived categories in "Tilting Theory and Cluster Combinatorics" by Buan-Marsh-Reineke-Reiten-Todorov challenging due to the fact that I have no idea how Auslander-Reiten translations are supposed to work in bounded derived categories. Would you please provide me some reference (such as a survey or lecture notes) so that I can understand this subject? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you read Happel's book  "Triangulated categories in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras"?  Then the next step is probably Keller's paper "Orbit triangulated categories".

Comment: I have already read a part of Happel's book before..I have gotten Keller's paper on your advice..

Comment: The AR translation, at least in Dynkin case, is translation to the left